# dbus example - on_name_lost intermediately after on_name_acquired

Tags: c, dbus

I was able to work with dbus as client, but if I compile https://github.com/bratsche/glib/blob/master/gio/tests/gdbus-example-server.c 
on_name_acquired callback is called and intermediately after on_name_lost callback is called.
The only changes that I made is that I use G_BUS_TYPE_SYSTEM instead of G_BUS_TYPE_SESSION

I only guess that this is some authentication issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike the session bus, the system bus has a security policy which prevents arbitrary processes from claiming arbitrary well-known names on the bus. You need to install a [configuration file](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-daemon.1.html#configuration_file) for the system bus to allow your service to own a name:

> Rules with the `own` or `own_prefix` attribute are checked when a
> connection attempts to own a well-known bus names. As a special case,
> `own="*"` matches any well-known bus name. The well-known session bus
> normally allows any connection to own any name, while the well-known
> system bus normally does not allow any connection to own any name,
> except where allowed by further configuration. System services that
> will own a name must install configuration that allows them to do so,
> usually via rules of the form `<policy user="some-system-user"><allow own="…"/></policy>`.

This means installing a configuration file like the following in `/usr/share/dbus-1/system.d/org.mydomain.MyService1.conf`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE busconfig PUBLIC
 "-//freedesktop//DTD D-BUS Bus Configuration 1.0//EN"
 "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/dbus/1.0/busconfig.dtd">
<busconfig>
  <!-- Only my-service-user can own the service -->
  <policy user="my-service-user">
    <allow own="org.mydomain.MyService1"/>
  </policy>

  <!-- Anyone can send messages to the service -->
  <policy context="default">
    <allow send_destination="org.mydomain.MyService1"/>
  </policy>
</busconfig>
```

You must then run your service’s process as the `my-service-user` user.

The [D-Bus API design tutorial section on security policies](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-api-design.html#security-policies) is relevant reading.